# sequelize: association is referencing to wrong foreignKey column name

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm struggling with this problem for hours, i cannot seem to find a fix to this confusing error. I am trying to make a query with joined table and show result with nested object.

So the tables are like this: `blogs` table is associated to `accounts` table through foreign key `accounts_id` on `blogs` table, this seems to be an easy join query, but i cannot make sequelize use the right foreign key column name as it thinks the foreign key is called as `account_id`

The models are defined this way:

accounts:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('accounts', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        ............
    }, {
        tableName: 'accounts',
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true
    });
```

blogs:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
    var model = sequelize.define("blogs", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        content: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        accounts_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        ............
    }, {
        tableName: "blogs",
        timestamps: false,
        underscored: true
    });

    model.belongsTo(sequelize.models.accounts);
    sequelize.models.accounts.hasMany(model, {targetKey: "accounts_id"});

    return model;
};
```

and the query is like this:

```
var criteria = {
    include: [$db.models.accounts]
};

return model.findAll(criteria);
```

but it throws `Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'blogs.account_id' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 6):

has many doesnt supports target key option
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4258

Can you try, point foregin key in both

```
    model.belongsTo(sequelize.models.accounts, {foreignKey: "accounts_id"});
    sequelize.models.accounts.hasMany(model, {foreignKey: "accounts_id"});
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have to set both `hasMany({ sourceKey` and `belongsTo({ targetKey`**

As of sequelize 6.14.0 to get custom join columns you should do something like:

```
const Country = sequelize.define('Country', {
  country_name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true },
});
const City = sequelize.define('City', {
  parent_country: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
  city_name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
});
Country.hasMany(City, { foreignKey: 'parent_country', sourceKey: 'country_name' } )
City.belongsTo(Country, { foreignKey: 'parent_country', targetKey: 'country_name' } )
```

Full runnable example at: [Sequelize targetKey not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818406/sequelize-targetkey-not-working/70821746#70821746)

Comment: Reference of [Sequelize v6 Documentation](https://sequelize.org/v6/manual/assocs.html)